# Javascript Converting a date to millisecond

Tags: javascript

I am building a counter down .
I have the following code:-

```
var date = new Date(res.data.created_at);
console.log(date); //Sat Jun 20 2020 23:52:05 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3); 
console.log(date); //Tue Jun 23 2020 23:52:05 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)
console.log(date.getMilliseconds()); //0
console.log(date.getTime()); //1592945525000
```

The counter library i am using is accepting a millisecond as initial count down value.
In the above code i want to get a date from api then add 3 days to it, after that get the milliseconds value from now date time to the 3 days added value.

Comment: You may be confusing a time interval with instant. The library takes a time interval. The value you should pass is the difference in milliseconds from Jun 23 to now

Something like:

const jun23 = new Date(2020, 6, 23)
const now = new Date()

const ms = jun23.getTime() - now.getTime()

Comment: In case you are trying to get milliseconds of now date - new Date().getTime()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Date.now()` to get the current timestamp, and just do a subtraction:

```
var endDate = new Date(res.data.created_at);
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 3);

var diffInMilliseconds = endDate.getTime() - Date.now();
```